# The meaning of Covariance

Tags: covariance

The positive covariance indicates that higher the average values of one variable tend to be paired with heigher than the average 
values of other variable. and the negtaive indicates that higher the average values of one variable tend to be paired with
 lower than the average values of the other variable. That what idicates the sign of the value of the covariance.
What about the value its self what does high covariance value or lower covariance means?

Comment: [This](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18058/how-would-you-explain-covariance-to-someone-who-understands-only-the-mean) is by far the best explanation I've ever seen on covariance.